# GSEA: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘keytypes’ for signature ‘"standardGeneric"’

Tags: r

I can't understand this problem.  Even when I use the data and code offered at https://learn.gencore.bio.nyu.edu/rna-seq-analysis/gene-set-enrichment-analysis/ , the problem also existed.

[image]

I did the analysis follow the official illustrate. As bellows:

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(enrichplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(org.Dm.eg.db)
library(DOSE)
library(biomaRt)

df = read.csv("~/lineagepaper/drosphila_example_de.csv", header=TRUE)

original_gene_list <- df$log2FoldChange

names(original_gene_list) <- df$X

gene_list<-na.omit(original_gene_list)

gene_list = sort(gene_list, decreasing = TRUE)
head(gene_list)
```

[image]

```
gse <- gseGO(geneList=gene_list, 
             ont ="ALL", 
             keyType = "ENSEMBL", 
             nPerm = 10000, 
             minGSSize = 3, 
             maxGSSize = 800, 
             pvalueCutoff = 0.05, 
             verbose = TRUE, 
             OrgDb = organism, 
             pAdjustMethod = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: What are you doing that creates that error in the title? Please edit the question and show what you did (in text, not a screenshot image) that made it happen. Include any relevant packages you may have attached.

Comment: Thanks.  I have detailed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem while working with the same tutorial and solved it this way .
So the argument OrgDb doesn't take in "org.Hs.eg.db" which is a string. Instead , put in the name of the annotation database directly for that argument.

Example:

```
gse <- gseGO(geneList=gene_list, 
             ont ="ALL", 
             keyType = "SYMBOL", 
             nPerm = 10000, 
             minGSSize = 3, 
             pvalueCutoff = 0.05, 
             verbose = TRUE, 
             OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db, 
             pAdjustMethod = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to this users answer, you can also read it in this way since this will tell it to pull directly from that package.

OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db::org.Hs.eg.db,